# How to trace site route in apache

Tags: wordpress, apache, ubuntu, virtual-hosts

UBUNTU + APACHE

I am running a few wordpress sites on one server (that I inherited) using VirtualHosts, and I need to configure ssl certificates for each site.

Before starting to set up certificates for each site, I tried entering each domain with the https prefix on the browser and noticed it redirects me to a site (with an invalid certificate) that is supposed to be disabled and does even show up when I run

```
apachectl -t -D DUMP_VHOSTS
```

I tried configuring the virtualhost entries for one of the sites with the valid certificate and it still goes to same old site. How can I completely disable and remove that site and the invalid certificate? I cannot find it anywhere on the server.

My Virtual host looks something like this

```
NameVirtualHost *:443

<VirtualHost *:443>
 ServerName www.yoursite.com
 DocumentRoot /var/www/site
 SSLEngine on
 SSLCertificateFile /path/to/www_yoursite_com.crt
 SSLCertificateKeyFile /path/to/www_yoursite_com.key
 SSLCertificateChainFile /path/to/DigiCertCA.crt
</VirtualHost>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to disable a virtual host configuration you just need to do:

```
sudo a2dissite sitename
sudo systemctl restart apache2
```

and the issue should be resolved